# File not found for valid image url

Tags: android

I have checked and tried so many solutions that are available here, but none of them worked for me. The image with my **url** is visible in browser but inside my android app it shows file not found exception, I changed image **url** in my app it did worked and showed me image

```
   final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Image...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();



        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(certUrl).resize(500,0).into(ivCertificate, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to get certificate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you share your **url and code** with question

Comment: are u using any library

Comment: I have updated my question, i can't share url

Comment: Why is the y-dimension zero? `.resize(500,0)` Also, assume that `ivCertificate` is an `ImageView`. In that case, Picasso tries to get the dimension from the view itself to resize to **exactly** that size, so `.resize()` will not be needed.

Comment: Also, please share Logcat errors, if any.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing slashes in your URL String?

Comment: @lidkxx yes i am very much sure about this

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana yes i have tried all the combinations still not able to show image and there no error in logcat also

Comment: Try adding a placeholder and an error image (image to replace placeholder in case of error). At least you will be able to see something. `Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder).error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error).into(imageView)`. Also, share Logcat logs.

Comment: There is no error shown in logcat i have added placeholder but now i have removed it

Comment: Inside which lifecycle method are you calling this? Are you saying it only doesn't work for only a SPECIFIC URL? If you paste a different URL like this https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg it works?

Comment: yes it is working for other url's

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys !! adding SSL Exceptions did trick for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Picasso` for that;

```
ImageView thumbnail;

Picasso.with(activity).load(certUrl).noFade().into(thumbNail);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your url contains **space** then you need to follow below steps.

```
imgUrl = imgUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

The above line replace all space with **"%20"**

```
String imgUrl = "your url";
imgUrl = imgUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgUrl)
.placeholder(R.drawable.category_placeholder)
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: there are no spaces in my url

Comment: Then remove resize property and check

Comment: can u share your url

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `Context`.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: share your URL.(remove if it contains blank space in that)

Comment: i cannot share url and it doesn't have spaces